# Do I need to change something in the cart class in Codeigniter to utilize both session variables and database data?

Tags: php, codeigniter

By default Codeigniter shopping cart class uses its built-in session functions. Session class in CI can be configured to use cookie or database, which means the shopping cart will **EITHER** use database or cookie to store session variables.

However for my site I want to implement this: when the user is not logged in, the cart uses cookie data; when the user is logged in, the cart uses data stored in database.  This means the cart class should be able to switch between cookie and database.

How can I achieve that while not making changes to the built-in cart class? If that's not possible I may have to rewrite the cart class which takes some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods possible.

1. Inherit your inbuilt card class and override the product_insert, product_update and product_delete methods. This is cleaner and provides you with better customizability. The feature you need is pretty trivial and you can do it with something like this.

   ```
   function product_insert() {   
     checkUserSignedIn();   
     if(true) {
       parent::product_insert();   
     } else {
       doYourthingHere();   
     } 
   }
   ```

override all the crud methods like this and you can achieve what you want.

1. Use the customized library

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/212926/P10/#1006680

it has some features that you need but still you will have to tweak it to suite your requirements exactly